# Shorthand For Loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, shorthand

I have three-rows code:

```
echo '<div>';
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) echo $i;
echo '</div>';
```

Is there any syntax or function let me rewrite above code in only ONE row, for example:

```
echo '<div>'.(for...).'</div>'; //error
```

Thanks

Comment: you want to make it harder to read and maintain - why?

Comment: In some case, it's not harder to read and maintain, I think. It's clear to see.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible, no you dont want to do it:

```
echo '<div>' . implode('', array_keys(array_fill(1,4,0))) . '</div>';
```

Comment: 0_o - Did you even ponder for a second and consider the poor world before you clicked "submit"?

Comment: Thanks Steve these types of answers are great for code golf

Answer (score 1):

While readability is completely personal opinion, there are "common" methods, guidelines, and coding standards which are used by a lot of developers.

And while you don't *need* to adhere to them, it is always up to you or the company you work for, some of these "ways" are just common sense regardless of your personal choice.

Even if there was a way to do it, why would you want to?
How far do you want to go mixing things together for *supposed* readability?

`echo` and a `loop` are completely different things, and should remain separate.

### Answer

In answer to your question, no, it is not possible because PHP needs to differentiate between different "things" - functions, echo statements, variable declaration and usage, etc.
The only things you can "mix" are things which PHP *allows* to be together, like having a variable in a function parenthesis (`function($someVar)`).

The only thing you could do (and again this has no point, but your choice) is to put it all on one line, like so:

```
echo '<div>'; for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) { echo $i; } echo '</div>';
```

But that looks terrible.
I want to *quickly* see different things - "ah an echo, it prints out XYZ", then I want to see a loop *separately* so I can see easily what the loop is doing.